# RecyclerView ScrollY always 0

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, recyclerview-layout

I have a RecyclerView inside a fragment. I need to be notified of scroll changes, so I added a callback to the `ScrollChange` event (which corresponds to the `SetOnScrollChangeListener` in classical Android API):

```
private void RecyclerViewScrollChange(object sender, View.ScrollChangeEventArgs e)
{
    int deltaY = e.ScrollY - e.OldScrollY;
}
```

The problem is that deltaY is always zero, because both ScrollY and OldScrollY are always zero. I am using vertical linear layout in the recycler view's layout manager, so the vertical dimension ought to be updated. What can cause this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

scrolling to Y position is getting using

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                Log.v("onScrolled", "dx:" + dx + " dy:" + dy);

             }
        });
```

Comment: I see that Xamarin's `ScrollChange` event wraps `setOnScrollChangeListener`, and there is no event wrapping `addOnScrollListener`. I switched to `addOnScrollListener` method and it works fine now.

Comment: The question is asking `scrollY`, this answer answering `dy`?? why this is the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

`View.SetOnScrollChangeListener()` was added in API level 23 which you can see here in the docs: [View.SetOnScrollChangeListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnScrollChangeListener(android.view.View.OnScrollChangeListener))

If your app should support versions before API level 23, a workaround is by adding a ScrollChangeListener to the `RecyclerView`'s `ViewTreeObserver' using [AddOnScrollChangedListener()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html#addOnScrollChangedListener(android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener)) as followed:

```
_recyclerView.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnScrollChangedListener(param);
```

Or adding a callback to the `ViewTreeObserver`'s [ScrollChanged](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.ScrollChanged/) event